# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null when setting innerhtml for hiddenfield

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

im am trying to set the value for a hiddenfield with a bootstrap radio button. I have an onCLick evnet on it and when it is clicked the value of the hiddenfield needs to be changed. Here is the buttons and the hiddenfield.

```
<div class="myRow">
        <div class="smallCol">
            <div class="myRow">
                <div class="smallCol title">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNewRFID" runat="server" Text="RFID etiketcode"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="myRow">
                <div class="smallCol">
                    <div class="btn-group hiddenRFIDValue" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" class="btn" name="options" onclick="getHiddenRFIDValue('Always')" id="alwaysRFID" value="Always" autocomplete="off">
                            Always
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" class="btn" name="options" onclick="getHiddenRFIDValue('Never')" id="neverRFID" value="Never" autocomplete="off">
                            Never
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" class="btn" name="options" onclick="getHiddenRFIDValue('Sometimes')" id="sometimesRFID" value="Sometimes" autocomplete="off">
                            Sometimes
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenRFIDValue" runat="server" />
```

and here is the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   onclick = function getHiddenRFIDValue(stringValue) {
       document.getElementById('hiddenRFIDValue').innerHTML = stringValue;
    }
</script>
```

Do any of you have an idear why i get the error?

Comment: check the generated html to see what is the actual id... you might have to set a clientId also to the hidden field

Comment: `onclick = function getHiddenRFIDValue(stringValue) {` should be `function getHiddenRFIDValue(stringValue) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with this.

```
<script>
    $(".hiddenRFIDValue .btn").click(function () {
        $("#MainContent_hiddenRFIDValue").val($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

When the HTML was generated it changed the id of the hidden field

Answer (score 0):

You must remove "onclick" variable, only

```
function getHiddenRFIDValue(stringValue) {
       document.getElementById('hiddenRFIDValue').innerHTML = stringValue;
    }
```

and

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenRFIDValue" runat="server" />
```

try replace on

```
<input type="hidden" ID="hiddenRFIDValue" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine If you just ommit onclick from function like

```
function getHiddenRFIDValue(stringValue) {
   document.getElementById('hiddenRFIDValue').innerHTML = stringValue;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cood1z7w/)